# Remove "Create blog" link from My Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, customization

what is the best way to remove the upper-right link "Create blog" from My Site ?

I have found this article, but I hope there's another solution than doing that !
[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx)

I'm using MOSS 2007.
Thanks for your help,

Raphaël

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Google query: **remove "create blog" link moss**

turned up this page and numerous others:

http://sfguyalex.blogspot.com/2008/08/hideremove-create-blog-link-on-my-site.html

--Jesse Taylor

Comment: oops, i did my previous query with Sharepoint instead of moss.
Thanks for your query !